# Tool generating hill slope forms (divergent, convergent, uniform) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, hydrology

Does anyone know a tool or procedure for generating a raster file of slope forms (divergent = upper slope wider than lower slope, convergent = upper slope narrower than lower slope and uniform = upper and lower slopes similar wide).

As input file, I have a high-resolution (1 m) DEM and the outline of the catchment.

I want to use the result for hydrological analysis and to subdivide the catchment.

I use QGIS version 3.22.6.

Maybe the exposition of the slopes and the inclination can be used for that?

Comment: Here is a qgis 2.18 reference to a SAGA tool  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/terrain_analysis_morphometry.html.  Here is the current SAGA link: https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/ta_morphometry.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "slope wider". But you might be able to use the Topographic Wetness Index. This is one of the outputs of the GRASS module `r.watershed`